# Why is my Django UpdateView not seeing my model data (specifically the id/pk)?

Tags: python, django, web-deployment

I'm working on a Django Project in which I have a model (Order) which holds various orders received from customers. I'm trying to update one of the Order fields (status) via id using UpdateView (CancelOrder). I've written the UpdateView and modified the urls.py, but when I try to update the status of an order via url I get the error: No order found matching the query, despite having several orders stored. My question is, why is the UpdateView not seeing my model data? Have I missed something?

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.exceptions import *
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView

from menu.models import Item, Order, Customer
from menu.forms import OrderForm, CustForm, UpdateForm
from .serializers import ItemSerializer
from rest_framework import generics

class CancelOrder(UpdateView):
    model = Order
    field = ('status',)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns, include
from . import views
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.CreateOrder, name='CreateOrder'),
    url(r'^vieworder/', views.ViewOrder, name='ViewOrder'),
    url(r'^confirmation/', views.ConfirmOrder, name='ConfirmOrder'),
    url(r'^api/$', views.ItemList.as_view()),
    url(r'^api/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ItemDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^cancel/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.CancelOrder.as_view(), name='CancelOrder'),
)

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

**Model**

```
class Order(models.Model):

    order_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    delivery_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='open')
    ordered_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)

    #user input
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    shipping_info = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    billing_info = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    total = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    surcharge = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: How are using this view/url? What are you passing in the POST?

Comment: Is that what needs to be done? In the tutorials I saw and read, they just seemed to just set up the updateview, add some lines to the urls.py and interact with the browser (manually type /cancel/id). I'm sure there are more practical ways to do this but I'm new to Django. What would you suggest?

Comment: Which tutorials did you read? Could you provide a link?

Comment: I watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Ez2NXOX9zY and read this https://gist.github.com/flaviamissi/1275204. Perhaps I misunderstood what they were trying to say.

Comment: That view should be enough for a simple update. Can you show the template?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the comments and doing a bit more research I realized that I didn't fully understand what I was trying to do; most importantly I didn't have a template. I've fixed the issue as follows:

**views.py**

```
class CancelOrder(UpdateView):
model = Order
fields = ('status',)
template_name = 'menu/order_form.html'

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('confirm')
```

template. I've fixed the issue as follows:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
url(r'^updateorder/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.CancelOrder.as_view(), name='cancel')
)

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

**template**

```
{% extends "menu/header.html" %}

{% block content %}

<form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
<div id='helper'>{% include 'menu/includes/helper.html' %}<div>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Cancel Order">
</form>
<p>*Type "cancelled" to cancel your order</p>

{% endblock %}
```

**helper**

```
{% for field in form %}
<div>
<div><span>{{field.errors}}</div></span>
<label>{{field.label_tag}}</label>
<div>{{field}}</div>
<div>
{% endfor %}
```

This solves the issue, thanks to everyone in the comments.